# On Florida machine recount - how limited to Senate/Gov/Agriculture

Tags: united-states, voting, florida

The machine recount required by FL law is underway. Are the scanning machines reprogrammed  to only tabulate senate, governors, and Ag.Secty?  Or do the scanners actually do a complete retabulation of all races?

Comment: Just in: regarding the machine recount - Palm County supervisor says that the software on the optical scanners requires that each ballot be scanned individually for each office/issue. -- Does that mean that when the ballots were initially scanned (for the first vote tabulation) each ballot had to be scanned as many times as there were offices or issues?   That's crazy !